# Extract video files embedded in an android app convert the .exo files to mp4 and save it to my PC

Tags: video, android, mp4, embedded

I wanted to extract video files embedded in an android app and save it to my PC. The videos are embedded in the app. There is no way to get the URL for the videos.

I tried getting the `.exo` files and then converting them to mp4, but it did not work.

How can I download/extract videos embedded in an android app, so that I can save them on my PC?

Answer (score 1):

First this is only segment from video. There is possibility other segments exist and they are required to reconstruct the video.

Second `.exo` files are encrypted so they can be played only on the device where they are downloaded.

For more information you can check [here](https://fileinfo.com/extension/exo).